# Flutter: Return a contacts number only using contact picker

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using the following plugin, "contact_picker 0.0.2" to pick a contact from my address book and return a phone number. The problem is it returns a contacts name, number and number type ( work ,home ) like so

Alessandro: +27 00 000 0000 (Work)

I've managed to get rid of most of it using this peice of code

```
onPressed: () async {
            Contact contact = await _contactPicker.selectContact();
            setState(() {

              _contact = contact;
              print(_contact.toString().replaceAll("+27 ", "").replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("(Work)", ""));  

            });
          },
```

but it still returns the users name like so
Alessandro:0000000000

How can I remove the users name or only return the last ten numbers of the contact

Comment: try `_contact.phoneNumber`, or `_contact.phoneNumber.number` / `_contact.phoneNumber.label`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get only the `phoneNumber.number` from contact class:

```
_contact.phoneNumber.number
```

[reference](https://github.com/goderbauer/contact_picker/blob/master/lib/contact_picker.dart)

> ```
>   /// The phone number of the contact.
>   final PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
> ```

Comment: @pskink okay, you are right, I've updated my answer.

Comment: and he just wants `phoneNumber.number` - as `PhoneNumber` keeps both `number` and `label` - ['$number ($label)'](https://github.com/goderbauer/contact_picker/blob/master/lib/contact_picker.dart#L63)

Comment: @pskink indeed I was just looking at that at that

Comment: @LebogangNkosi next time just take a look into the sources - `Control - left click` in android studio

Comment: It does return the number and I would just use _contact.replaceAll("  ", "") to remove empty spaces